# Formatting an Echo Statement in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, interpolation, string-interpolation

What is the proper way to reformat this PHP statement to say "Copyright © 2013 My Company. All rights reserved." (without quotes)?

`<?php _e('All Rights Reserved', 'mycompany'); ?> <a href="/">My Company</a> &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?>`

As of right now, the above statement echoes "All Rights Reserved My Company © 2013".

Comment: Should tag this as wordpress if it is. (I'm not sure if it *is* wordpress, so not tagging!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working in Wordpress, this solution utilizes the Internationalization feature (unt-tested, please let me know if this doesn't work at expected!):

```
<?php _e('Copyright &copy; ' . date('Y', time()) . ' My Company. All rights reserved.', 'mycompany');
```

Otherwise a straight up PHP solution is:

```
<?php print 'Copyright &copy; ' . date('Y', time()) . ' My Company. All rights reserved.'; ?>
```

Comment: It is more polite to show the copyright symbol using HTML entities :) `&#169;`

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Yes, assuming there still exist cases where UTF-8 may not be used (although, highly unlikely now).

Comment: You're right, and fixed. It's better to use the copyright symbol in an html-friendly manner for better compatibility with ASCII-only implementations, or other encordings in which the 169 value may normally represent a different character.

Comment: hang on.  This solution leaves out the OP's internationalization hook. _e